# Why is this rocket transparent, and why is there a nozzle in the nose, pointing up?

Tags: history, identify-this-object, fairings, balloons, sounding-rocket

The tough  question [NASA at sIxty years, will there be a new moonshot mandate?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29770/12102) links to the NASA YouTube video [NASA 60th: How It All Began](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VV6QeZFaVSQ) which shows a lot of really nice, historical file footage and stills.

At about `01:56` there is a still of an engineer standing next to what looks like a sounding rocket, or a model of one, that is transparent. Behind the engineer is an inflatable, metallized balloon, smaller, but similar to the ones shown in the question [Did Echo 2 remain spherical without requiring gas pressure? If so, how is this known to be true?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29513/12102), and it looks like an un-inflated balloon is stowed in a compartment of the transparent rocket as well.

Most likely, the rocket is transparent because it is just a model, but I am still wondering what that thing is that looks like a nozzle, pointing up, in the cone.

**below:** Screen shot from the NASA YouTube video [NASA 60th: How It All Began](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29513/12102).

*Click for full size.*

[image]

Comment: The outside shape of that model looks like Explorer 1 but the contents don't match that satellite. They don't match Echo 1 either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a model of a Vanguard nosecone / third stage with an "IGY magnetometer satellite" at the top. The sphere is the "Sub-Satellite", a precursor of Project Echo.

[image]

Sad ending: It blew up in the launch attempt of the Vanguard [SLV-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanguard_SLV-5) vehicle.

Another picture of the model is found in the same document (source linked below).

[image]

[Source](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4308/ch6.htm)

The official [NASA history of Project Vanguard](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4202.pdf) also calls it a "magnetometer". (page 226)

The final, real-world payload may not have looked like this model.  It may have looked more like Vanguard 3 shown in the answer to this question: [This BBC photo does not show a replica of Vanguard-1, what might it be?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23286/this-bbc-photo-does-not-show-a-replica-of-vanguard-1-what-might-it-be)

Comment: Thanks, I will dig into this after coffee. I'm guessing IGY is *[International Geophysical Year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Geophysical_Year)* where nailing the Earth's oblateness through orbital tracking was one of the major goals, and the [Fischer Ellipsoid](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23861/12102) of 1960 was a result, but I'll start to read up on the importance of magnetometers as well. To double check, this https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKSwx.jpg is an "IGY magnetometer satellite"?

Comment: That's what the source document calls it, but I think it's an early design model.  The flight models seem to be "spheres with a cylinder attached" like Vanguard 3.  I notice quite a few subtle differences between the model in the question and the one in the answer.