# Function and nature of the RHC/LCH pair of cables to New Horizons's dish antenna secondary mirror?

Tags: new-horizons, radio-communication, electronics, antenna

Spaceflight 101's [New Horizons Spacecraft Overview](http://spaceflight101.com/newhorizons/spacecraft-overview/) is full of interesting information and shows this **RF Comm System Block Diagram**. The thin (red) lines to the dish antenna area are coaxial cables and the thick (blue) lines are waveguides. Switching is done at the waveguide level.

Like Voyager, the secondary mirror reflects some signals to a pair of coaxial couplers at the secondary focus, while allows other signals to pass through to the primary focus to another pair of coaxial couplers. Each pair has an RHC and LHC label, but I don't know what those mean.

However, there is a *third pair* of coaxial cables that appear to end *on the surface of the secondary reflector* and would therefore not be in focus.

What is the function and nature of this third RHC/LCH pair?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LHC is Left-Handed Circularly polarized, and RHC is Right-Handed Circularly polarized.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_polarization#Left-/right-handedness_conventions).  As explained in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30601/26446), spacecraft radio signals are often circularly polarized, because -- unlike linearly polarized radio waves -- they don't care about the attitudes of the transmitter or receiver.

There are three different "gains" on the antenna.  The lowest-gain is for strong signals (i.e. close to Earth), but is closest to omnidirectional.  The highest gain can handle weak signals, but the dish has to be aligned precisely with the source.

[image]
[Source](https://cs.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soubor:New_Horizons_1.jpg) Cropped.

[image]
[Source](http://www.ninfinger.org/models/vault2005/New%20Horizons/index.html)

[image]
[Source](https://www.nasa.gov/images/nh-rex-instrument)

This diagram [shows the 3 antennas](http://www.vox.com/2015/4/14/8412031/pluto-new-horizons): 
[image]

[The primary dish](http://www.boulder.swri.edu/~tcase/NH%20RF%20Telecom%20Sys%20ID1369%20FINAL_Deboy.pdf) for the medium-gain antenna is placed on top of the secondary reflector of the high-gain antenna. The LGA is placed on top of the feed horn of the MGA.

Comment: @Hobbes ah, the key is that the medium gain antenna's parabolic dish is almost coincident with the *backside* of the high gain antenna's secondary reflector. It's a 30cm dish in the center of the 2.1 m dish! It turns out that [the original Spaceflight 101 article](http://spaceflight101.com/newhorizons/spacecraft-overview/) mentions this. This is really cute! Let's see if we can find a good image of that somewhere. On **page 10** in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.4288.pdf "The secondary reflector assembly consists of a Medium Gain Antenna (MGA) and the HGA subreflector."

Comment: Also possibly helpful: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.472.8206&rep=rep1&type=pdf This one is paywalled: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1367922 and so is https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4384378

Comment: [1](https://cs.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soubor:New_Horizons_1.jpg), [2](https://spaceflightnow.com/2015/07/13/see-nasas-pluto-explorer-before-embarkment-from-earth/), [3](https://historicspacecraft.com/Probes_Outer_Planets.html#New-Horizons), [4](http://www.ninfinger.org/models/vault2005/New%20Horizons/index.html), [5](https://magazine.uc.edu/issues/0316/pluto.html), [6](https://ece.osu.edu/news/2015/06/ohio-state-and-new-horizons-mission-pluto) [7](https://ece.osu.edu/sites/ece.osu.edu/files/uploads/new_horizons_press_release.pdf), [8](https://www.qualitydigest.com/pdfs/CMSC1.pdf)

Comment: [9 video](https://youtu.be/I6BbSFLIHjc),