# What was so "Mini" about Minitrack?

Tags: history, tracking, military, vanguard

[image: screen shot from Vanguard 60th Anniversary: A Look Back]

In the US Naval Research Laboratory video [Vanguard 60th Anniversary: A Look Back](https://youtu.be/HS72o86aeZo) Roger L. Easton says:

> Now, how did Vanguard Start?
>
> I think it’s fair to say that Milt Rosen started the Vanguard project, and in addition started what became Minitrack. We had been working on an X-band device for tracking the Viking rocket; I remember meeting Milt in the hall, and him saying to me “Couldn’t we reduce the frequency of that device and use it for tracking the satellite?”
>
> I said I’d look into it, and it just happened that Dr. Jacob Freeman had analyzed the X-band system, so it was a small task to change it to a lower frequency. **And this I succeeded in doing, and the result was Minitrack, which was named by John Mengel.**

Presumably Minitrack's individual footprints, global distribution of sites, wavelengths, dipole antenna sizes and interferometric baselines were all larger than its X-band progenitor, so I'm curious what was so "Mini" about Minitrack?

video cued at `02:53`:

Comment: That looks quite small for something called "Mini". Compare with a [Minicomputer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicomputer) or a [Mini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini) for example :D

Comment: @AaronF the satellite is called [Vanguard 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanguard_1)(also [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23286/12102)). The [Minitrak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minitrack) sites were quite large (shown in the screen shot). See Figure 2-2 in [OM's 2nd link](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19730015552.pdf).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The name actually comes from the name of the *proposed satellite*

> The name of the system first appeared early in April 1955 on an NRL
>   document entitled "Proposal for Minimum Trackable Satellite
>   (Minitrack)."

NRL = Naval Research Laboratory

[Final Report for the Minitrack Tracking Function Description](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19730015552.pdf)

> In early April 1955, Milton Rosen, John Mengel, and Roger Easton
>   assembled informally at NRL  and generated a document entitled,
>   "Proposal for Minimum Trackable Satellite (Minitrack)." No date and no
>   authors are listed on this key report; but, according to Rosen, it
>   preceded only by a few days a more formal report with the title, "A
>   Scientific Satellite Program,'' dated April 13, 1955, and written by
>   the NRL Rocket Development Branch. Appendix B of this document was
>   labeled, "The Minitrack System'' and was nearly identical to its
>   predecessor of a few days.

[THE EVOLUTION OF THE SATELLITE TRACKING AND DATA ACQUISITION NETWORK (STADAN)](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19670008308.pdf)

Comment: This is interesting; "Minimum Trackable" rather than "Minimally Trackable" or "Minimal, Trackable". I wonder if there's any chance that they wanted to *track some minimum of some kind*, rather than find the minimal system that provided a trackable satellite? Probably though it was simply completed in haste and there's just a slight grammatical error in the title.

Comment: I think they wanted to build *the smallest satellite that they could track by radio*. Check page 14 in the 2nd reference for a discussion of radio vs optical tracking.

Comment: Ya I guess so, I just found another "minimum" [Minimum Orbital Unmanned Satellite Earth (MOUSE)](https://www.bis-space.com/what-we-do/projects/project-mouse) and here's a PDF: [Studies of a minimum orbital unmanned satellite of the Earth ...](https://www.bis-space.com/what-we-do/projects/project-mouse)

Comment: Mass of the orbiter was obs. a big concern!

Comment: These make for a great read, thanks!

Comment: Proposal for [the] Minimum [size of transmitter needed onboard a satellite to be a] Trackable Satellite. - it's a title, I don't see a grammatical error. And I don't see anything here that I didn't just read on Wikipedia. Can we get page 14?

Comment: @Mazura I see what you mean, okay not a grammatical error.